# Adding LIMIT to a query

Tags: php, mysql, join, limit

I'm trying to edit a query and add `LIMIT` to it and it's taking a while. Can you help me out a little?

Here's the working query:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM events INNER JOIN event_performers ON events.ID = event_performers.eventID WHERE event_performers.performerID = '898' ORDER BY events.ID");
```

I want to add `LIMIT ' . $offset . ', ' . $rowsPerPage` to it but am getting errors.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: **What are the errors you're getting?** We absolutely cannot help you if you don't tell us what's not working.

Comment: What are the errors? And where did your lunch go?

Comment: What did you try and what was the error you were getting?

Comment: what kind of errors? what values $offset and $rowsPerPage values contain?

Comment: I tried : $result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM events LIMIT ' . $offset . ', ' . $rowsPerPage . "INNER JOIN event_performers ON events.ID = event_performers.eventID WHERE event_performers.performerID = '898' ORDER BY events.ID"); and the error was: 
Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\prime\demo\pagination3.php on line 20

Comment: Limit should be placed at last like, "SELECT * FROM `your_table` LIMIT 0, 10" 0 is offset and 10 is row per page.

Comment: That error has nothing to do with the one line of code supplied containing a query! Your passing wrong values to mysql_fetch_array() somewhere later in your code, are you sure it's the query that is the problem? And the limit should at least be after the join and where.

Comment: And you get MySQL errors by calling `mysql_error()`. @Sheikh Heera put this as an answer so he can accept it. =)

Comment: Thank you Sheikh and Basti. That fixed me up.

Comment: Answered it now and thanks Basti.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Limit should be placed at last like, "SELECT * FROM your_table LIMIT 0, 10" 0 is offset and 10 is row per page, may be it should be

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM events INNER JOIN event_performers ON events.ID = event_performers.eventID WHERE event_performers.performerID = '898' ORDER BY events.ID LIMIT ".$offset.", ". $rowsPerPage);
```